# iOS Objective-C XCode: Logging Breakpoints and "magic" variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use breakpoints for logging instead of `NSLog`, but I am having trouble accessing the "magic" compiler variables like `__FUNCTION__`, `__FILE__`, etc.

Neither `Debugger Command` nor `Log Message` breakpoints seem to evaluate the variables in the same way as NSLog.

`NSLog(@"%s", __FILE__)` results in correct debug output of `/Users/nbirkholz/Documents/project_name/folder_name/file_name.m`

When I set a `Debugger Command` breakpoint of `po __FILE__` I receive debug output of `"Parse" { 'P' 'a' 'r' 's' 'e' <nil>}`

When I use `p __FILE__` I receive debug output of `(const char [6]) $1 = "Parse"`

Similar results ensue from `p`/`po` `__func__`/`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`/`__FUNCTION__`/`__LINE__`

`po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file is: %s", __FILE__]` results in
`error: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2`

`po (void)NSLog(@"the file is: %s", __FILE__)` returns `<timestamp> <module> the file is: Parse`

`expr`/`expression` `(void)NSLog(@"the file is: %s", __FILE__)` gives the same results.

Similarly, adding a `Log Message` breakpoint either fails to evaluate the expression at all or produces similar results, I can't seem to find an expression syntax that works encased in `@ @`

For example a `Log Message` of `the file is @__FILE__@` begets `the file is "Parse"`

Is there a way to get this to work without adding an `NSLog()` to the code directly and get it to properly evaluate the variable?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. You seem to be seeking out how to use these compiler variables with logging but not with NSLog, yet you seem to give working examples, "When I use p `__FILE__` I receive debug output of (const char [6]) $1 = "Parse""—what were you expecting?

Comment: @CuriousRabbit Updated the question. The output is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "Magic variables" are actually macros whose value is derived during compilation at the point they are referenced. They will not have the same value at debug time as they have at compile time. In fact, at debug time, you are most likely getting the variable's value as compiled into the debugger. I.E., not the file name of that code from MySpecialProgram, but the file name of the code executing in the debugger, likely the command parser.

Either put the logging in the code, as in:

```
NSLog(@"this is %s line %d function %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
```

or assign the vars to something you can access:

```
char[] foo = __FILE__;
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation referring to them as variables and the accessor-like syntax confused me about them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure here but afaik these are preprocessor macros, I think you can't get these to work in runtime.